# Why are the embeddings of tokens multiplied by $\sqrt D$ (note not divided by square root of D) in a transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, transformers

Why does the transformer tutorial in PyTorch have a multiplication by sqrt number of inputs? I know there is a division by sqrt(D) in the multiheaded self attention, but why is there something similar to with the output of the encoder? Especially because the original paper doesn't seem to mention it.

In particular (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/translation_transformer.html):

```
src = self.encoder(src) * math.sqrt(self.ninp)
```

or this (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html):

```
# helper Module to convert tensor of input indices into corresponding tensor of token embeddings
class TokenEmbedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size: int, emb_size):
        super(TokenEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
        self.emb_size = emb_size

    def forward(self, tokens: Tensor):
        return self.embedding(tokens.long()) * math.sqrt(self.emb_size)
```

Note that I am aware that the Attention layer has this equation:

$$
\alpha = Attention(Q,K,V) = SoftMax( \frac{ Q K^\top }{\sqrt{D}} ) V
$$

and they argue why about it in the paper in a one of the margins (something about sum of variance being 1).

Is this related to that comment and how is it related? Is this mentioned in the original paper?

cross posted:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-the-transformer-tutorial-have-a-multiplication-by-square-root-of-the-number-of-inputs/126738/6
- https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/okfd7g/why_does_the_embedding_of_tokens_to_the/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/op0z2t/why_are_the_embeddings_of_tokens_multiplied_by/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/LanguageTechnology/comments/op13ep/why_are_the_embeddings_of_tokens_multiplied_by/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/opcnwy/why_are_the_embeddings_of_tokens_multiplied_by/
- https://qr.ae/pGuVsC

Comment: Good question. How come you didn't ask in /r/ML instead of these tier-2 subreddits?

Comment: @bobcat I think there are issues posting things there in weekdays. Since I don't work on weekends I never end up being able to post there.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the weights in word embeddings get initialized with zero mean and unit variance. Also, the embeddings get multiplied by `sqrt(d)` **before** being added to the positional encoding. The positional encoding is also on the same scale as the embeddings.

My hypothesis is that the authors tried rescaling the embeddings by various numbers (as they certainly did with attention), and this particular rescaling happened to work, because it made the embeddings much bigger than the positional encodings (initially). The positional encodings are necessary, but they probably shouldn't be as "loud" as the words themselves.

Answer (score 0):

We multiply because we use learned embeddings to convert the input tokens and output tokens to vectors of dimension `d_model` in the embedding layer. Refer `Section 3.4` on `Embeddings and Softmax` of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf). You'd also see that an object of `TokenEmbedding` is [used](https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/blob/f3543da1d62a0dcb6549c8580db0419138899958/beginner_source/translation_transformer.py#L145) in `Seq2SeqTransformer` for source and target token embeddings.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in the transformer paper 'Attention is all you need', the embedding matrix in the input and the pre-softmax linear transformation in the linear layer outside the decoder block share the same projection matrix parameters.
2. vocab_size->d in the embedding matrix W, and d->vocab_size in the pre-softmax linear transformation matrix W^T in the linear layer.
3. Sharing the parameters in the matrix related to embedding is called tied-embedding. The parameters are initialized with Xavier with N(0,1/sqrt(d)). So multiplying sqrt(d) keep the word embedding to stay with N(0,1).
4. The original position embedding (cos/sin) can be considered as hard-code. So the the variance of position embedding is zero. Adding position embedding and word embedding (scaled sqrt(d)) still makes the variance of the combined embedding 1.

Answer (score 0):

In deep neural network layers, we want to retain the signals having normal distributions, and avoid diminishing and exploding gradients. This is the primary goal of weight initialization such as Xavier or He.

As demonstrated [Building makemore Part 3: Activations & Gradients, BatchNorm](https://youtu.be/P6sfmUTpUmc?t=5527), the activation functions are basically squashing `(-inf to inf)` range into `(0, 1)` or `(-1, 1)` or `(0,)`. Because of this, the variance of layer output signal tends to shrink causing difficulties to maintain normal distribution. To alleviate the this squashing effect, weight initializations are incorporating expanding gain such as $\sqrt{2}$ for ReLU or $5/3$ for tanh activation functions.

Hence, what we need to look for is where such a squashing effect is occurring, which the expanding effect of the multiplying with $\sqrt(D)$ will alleviate it.

The Transformer Architecture does not use Activation Functions except the ReLU at the Position Wise Feed Forward sub layer. Then, this is the place to look at. Or, look at how the embedding layer weights are initialized which may require the alleviation by $\sqrt(D)$.